# Unable to send notification with GCM for a chrome app, says "Insufficient Permission"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-cloud-messaging, google-chrome-app

Here are the complete steps I followed:

- Registered an app on Google Dev Console, enabled APIs for `Google+ API` and `Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome`.
- Under Credentials, created a new Client of type `Web Application`.
- Set the redirect uri back to my server (running on my VPS). Now I have `Client ID` and `Client Secret`
- Used this `Client ID` and `Client Secret` to get a `refresh token` (by sending `access_type=offline`)
- Using this `refresh token` got a new `access token` by running following on my local machine:

  ```
  curl -s https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "client_secret=<your client secret here>&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<your refresh token here>&client_id=<your client id here>" | grep "access_token" | awk -F\" '{print $4}'
  ```
- I installed the [official sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/push-sample-app) on my machine and after launching it, it showed me the channel id. Now I tried to send a push notification with the `access token` acquired earlier and to his `channel id`

  ```
  curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN HERE>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/gcm_for_chrome/v1/messages -d "{'channelId': '<CHANNEL ID HERE>', 'subchannelId': '0', 'payload': 'Hello World'}"
  ```

I am getting following response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Why so? How do I resolve it? And I have not made any changes to the sample chrome app. I double looked for instructions and in code if I had to mention my `client id`, but seems its not required. So, does that mean I can send notification to anyone if I have their `channel id`?

The email ID I used to create new app and the email with I signed in Chrome is same, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from my forthcoming book, "If you’re struggling with client IDs, client secrets, redirect URIs, refresh tokens, and access tokens, you have the wrong API." Use Google Cloud Messaging for Android. Do not turn on Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome, as that is for the old pushMessaging API. You want to use the newer GCM API. The GCM API doc has some links to other documentation, which has to be read very carefully, and the instructions have to be followed precisely. Fortunately, the GCM API is about 1000 times easier to set up and use than the old pushMessaging API.

I don't know to what extent Google's examples have been updated and, even for those that have been, the terminology used in the example may be out of date. There is another question posted here, perhaps from you, in which the example is confusing app key with API key. It's a mess.

Comment: even to send notifications for Chrome, I have to use `Google Cloud Messaging for Android` ?

Comment: Correct. GCM for Chrome goes with the now obsolete pushMessaging API, and GCM for Android goes with the newer gcm API. This is a good thing, as it means that both Google platforms have a common message distributor. Of course, GCM for Android needs to be named, but, as you already know, Google is very dilatory when it comes to updating their nomenclature. I would also say that any other OS vendor would have the same problem if (1) they had two OSes that they consider strategic, and (2) they changed them as often as Google does. Stay loose! Stay hungry! ;-)